# Dimming the LED for iPhone 5 flashlight app in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6

I am looking to dim the flashlight's LED with a slider option.  I know Apple supports this for iOS 6 however, I am not really sure what code to use.  Here is the code I have currently in the .m file.

```
-(IBAction)torchOn:(id)sender;
{
    onButton.hidden = YES;
    offButton.hidden = NO;

    onView.hidden = NO;
    offView.hidden = YES;


    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if(success)
        {
            [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}


-(IBAction)torchOff:(id)sender;
{
    onButton.hidden = NO;
    offButton.hidden = YES;

    onView.hidden = YES;
    offView.hidden = NO;

    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if(success)
        {
            [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does that not work? it seems ok to me

Comment: This is turns the light on an off.  I need to dim the light with a slider

Comment: See my answer. I have verified that it works on a device.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`- (BOOL)setTorchModeOnWithLevel:(float)torchLevel error:(NSError **)outError`

Does what you want. However, from what I can see, it only updates in certain intervals (~0.2).

```
AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
[device lockForConfiguration:nil];
[device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:slider.value error:NULL];
[device unlockForConfiguration];
```

**Edit - Full Example:**

Here is a UISlider. You need to add an IBAction outlet to your slider or programmatically add a target (like I do):

```
UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 20.0f, 280.0f, 40.0f)];
slider.maximumValue = 1.0f;
slider.minimumValue = 0.0f;
[slider setContinuous:YES];
[slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:slider];
```

Then, in response to the slider changing:

```
- (void)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider
{
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
    [device setTorchModeOnWithLevel:slider.value error:NULL];
    [device unlockForConfiguration];
}
```

Comment: I have added this but not sure I am adding it in the correct place.  Do I add this under another IBAction named torchDim?

Comment: Added example code. You need a callback whenever the UISlider's value changes, and then you can set that value as the `torchLevel`

Comment: So where does the BOOL code go.  Do I place that below like I have in my IBAction for torchOn?

Comment: Look at my `sliderDidChange:` example. Yes, you call `setTorchModeOnWithLevel:error:` in some IBAction of yours called torchDim, just like your torchOn and torchOff.

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you.  I am so close to this.  I get this warning " Local declaration of 'slider' hides instance variable.

Comment: Presumably you have either `- (void)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider` or `- (IBAction)sliderDidChange:(UISlider *)slider`, but you also have a `@property (nonatomic, strong) UISlider *slider` or `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UISlider *slider` in the header declaration.

On the line where you are receiving the area, rename `slider` to `localSlider`, or whatever you like.

Comment: That took care of the errors. The app crashes when it is run and I get a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" but no issues. Strange.

Comment: Got it!! I didn't map the slider to the IBaction on the xib file. But it's throwing two sliders for some reason.  I just need to play.

Answer (score 0):

If there are two sliders it's because the slider is set in the m. file you have to delete the `[self.view addSubview:slider];` part of the code.